# Error: Image Optimization using Next.js default loader is not compatible with `next export`

Tags: next.js, vercel

I got this error when deploying Next.js to Netlify.

```
Error: Image Optimization using Next.js default loader is not compatible with `next export`.

Possible solutions:

6:47:15 AM:   - Use `next start`, which starts the Image Optimization API.
6:47:15 AM:   - Use Vercel to deploy, which supports Image Optimization.
6:47:15 AM:   - Configure a third-party loader in `next.config.js`.
6:47:15 AM:  -  Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/export-image-api.
6:47:15 AM:   at exportApp (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:14:712)
```

The problem does not occur when deploying to Vercel.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

From Next.js 12.3, you can completely disable `next/image` Image Optimization using the `unoptimized` configuration in `next.config.js`. This avoids having to use a third-party provider to optimize the image when using `next/export`.

From the [`next/image`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#unoptimized) documentation:

> `unoptimized` - When true, the source image will be served as-is
> instead of changing quality, size, or format. Defaults to `false`.

```js
module.exports = {
    images: {
        unoptimized: true
    }
}
```

---

Before Next.js 12.3 and from 12.2, the `unoptimized` configuration was still experimental and could be enabled under the `experimental` flag.

```js
module.exports = {
    experimental: {
        images: {
            unoptimized: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my use case would benefit from image optimization so I went with a loader but I'm glad that choosing to not go with one was one the first answers here.

Answer (score 74):

## use `akamai`

setting `images.loader` to `'imgix'` caused dev and build errors.

i used this instead:

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  images: {
    loader: 'akamai',
    path: '',
  },
}
```

###### it just works for all i care about.

possible values for `images.loader` are: [ default, imgix, cloudinary, akamai, custom ]
reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image-legacy#built-in-loaders

Comment: For me it worked after setting path: '/'

Comment: Does akamai do lazy loading of images?

Comment: @mihca lazy loading is the default behavior. see: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loading

Comment: I've lost a whole day to fix this problem. Finally I wear out problem by this answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 31):

Seems you use next/images.
But `next/images` don't work with static pages (generated with `next export`)
For static pages use this image-optimizer : [next-optimized-images](https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-optimized-images) instead

Comment: Wow, thanks for this answer, but I couldn't find a way to lazy load the images using this dependency. Do you know a way of doing this?

Comment: @R.Karlus Should be included. See the docs for it by searching for `lazy`: https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-optimized-images

Answer (score 15):

I faced the same problem when using `next export` command. I still receive this error:

> Error: Image Optimization using Next.js' default loader is not compatible with `next export`.
> Possible solutions:
>
> - Use `next start` to run a server, which includes the Image Optimization API.
> - Use any provider which supports Image Optimization (like Vercel).
> - Configure a third-party loader in `next.config.js`.
> - Use the `loader` prop for `next/image`.

So, to make my custom loader working correctly, I needed
to set a path to an empty string:

```js
module.exports = {
  // https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21079
  // Remove this workaround whenever the issue is fixed
  images: {
    loader: 'imgix',
    path: '',
  },
}
```

*BUT, when I open the resultant `index.html` file, none of the images or JS loaded.*

So, for those who facing this also, please try to set the path to a `/` as such:

```js
module.exports = {
  // https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/21079
  // Remove this workaround whenever the issue is fixed
  images: {
    loader: 'imgix',
    path: '/',
  },
}
```

Comment: Is this next.config.js file ?

Comment: @DeepKakkar Yes, in the `next.config.js` file

Comment: will this work if I will not deploy on Vercel? , just need to export build using `next export` . Currently getting Image optimization error during export

Comment: @DeepKakkar Yes, it should work elsewhere after this workaround. I tested it in Netlify and the error went away

Comment: This worked for me when I replaced all <Image/> from next/image to a simple <img/> tag

Answer (score 1):

Next.js deployed on Vercel does not have this error.

This can also be solved using a local image loader **This will disable Image Optimization**

// imageLoader.js

```js
export default function imageLoader({ src, width, quality }) {
  return `https://<app-address.domain>${src}?w=${width}?q=${quality || 75}`;
}
```

Then in your app config

//next.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  assetPrefix: "./",
  images: {
    loader: "custom",
    loaderFile: "./utils/imageLoader.js",  // <= Location of image loader
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently the docs give you two choices:

1. [{loader: "custom"} (a global config)](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/images)
2. [loader prop (requires a custom Img component)](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#loader)

Solution 1: In `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  images: {
    loader: 'custom',
    loaderFile: './my/image/loader.js',
  },
}
```

The docs for this config no longer enumerate more options for the `loader` attribute besides `custom`. This was the only it way it worked for me despite other posters pointing out where the codebase suggests they are still supported.

Solution 2: The other option would look similar to the following example where you create a new HOC for images and include the image loader for your vendor. Custom loader functions vary between different image optimization vendors so this is just the currently available one for imgix:

```js
import Image from 'next/image'

function imageLoader({ src, width, quality }) {
  const url = new URL(`https://xyz.imgix.net/${src}`);
  const params = url.searchParams;
  params.set('auto', params.getAll('auto').join(',') || 'format');
  params.set('fit', params.get('fit') || 'max');
  params.set('w', params.get('w') || width.toString());
  params.set('q', (quality || 50).toString());
  return url.href;
}
 
function Img(props) {
  return (
    <Image 
      loader={imageLoader}
      alt={props.alt} 
      src={props.src} 
      width={props.width}
      height={props.height}
    />
  )
}

export default Img;
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is regarding Image/next, I was facing same error while "next build", than i use `<img/>` instead of `<Image/>` in the project and re-build it by `npm run build` and it resolves the error.